# Adding an animation to an image through OnClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image gallery where the user clicks on a small thumbnail image and this image is displayed as a larger version "Polaroid img" in my case. What I want to do is add a animation to the large image so that its opacity changes from 0 to 1 each time a new image is displayed there.

I cant figure out in my JavaScript why the class isn't been added and removed.

Thanks

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Meet some of the Characters</h1>
  <div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="Polaroid">
      <img src="images/imgage1.jpg" id="LargeImage">
      <div class="PolaroidText" id="LargeImageText">Image 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage1.jpg" alt="Image 1" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage2.jpg" alt="Image 2" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage3.jpg" alt="Image 3" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage4.jpg" alt="Image 4" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage5.jpg" alt="Image 5" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage6.jpg" alt="Image 6" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="images/imgage7.jpg" alt="Image 7" onclick="ClickImage(this)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.boxContainer
{
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.Polaroid
{ 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
  max-width: 2058px;
    transform: rotate(2deg); 
    margin-top: 50px; 
    margin-bottom: 50px; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.Polaroid img
{
  opacity: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #949baa;
  transition: opacity 2s ease !important;
}

.PolaroidText
{
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;

}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(2deg); 
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.column img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 5px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 9999;

}
.PoloaroidAnim
{
   animation-name: FadeImage;
  -webkit-animation-name FadeImage;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes FadeImage
{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
function ClickImage(smallimg)
{
   var lgImage = document.getElementById("LargeImage");
   var lgImageText = document.getElementById("LargeImageText");

   lgImage.addClass("PoloaroidAnim").one("webkitAnimationEnd", 
   remove(lgImage));
   lgImage.src = smallimg.src;

   lgImageText.innerHTML = smallimg.alt;
}
function remove(img)
{
  img.removeClass("PoloaroidAnim");
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain javascript? The .addClass is jQuery feature. If you are working in plain JS you should do this: var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";

Comment: Plain JavaScript, would you use JQuery?

Comment: You are calling addClass function which is jQuery feature and is not available in plain JS. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using plain JS, then the addClass function doesn't exists, so you should add the class like this:

```
var lgImage = document.getElementById("LargeImage");
lgImage.className += " PolaroidAnim";
```

The same goes for the other functions you are using (removeClass, one) - they are from the jQuery library.

If you use jQuery then you should select the element like this: `var lgImage = $("#LargeImage");` and not by `getElementById` because that is not a jQuery object and then the `addClass` function is not defined.

Comment: thanks for the help, I went down the Plain JS route, I encounted a problem when removing the class as i when i removed the class, i was being left with NaN. This was sorted out by using classList.add() and classList.remove() inside the setTimeout()